# org-mode ordered list with description

Tags: org-mode

I would really love to be able to create an ordered list in org-mode that also has descriptions for each item.  I've added an example below. The first option works as expected.  The second fails and prints out the description separator verbatim.  I've also created a third option manually that shows what I think it should look like when it works.  Is there anyway I can create this automatically? Meaning that "Ordered List with Descriptions" would produce the same output as "Fake Ordered List with Descriptions".

```
* Unordered List with Descriptions
- item1 :: item one
- item2 :: item two
- item3 :: item three

* Ordered List with Descriptions
1. item1 :: item one
2. item2 :: item two
3. item3 :: item three

* Ordered List with Fake Descriptions
1. *item1* item one
2. *item2* item two
3. *item3* item three
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? What input do you want to provide to get the desired output?

Comment: I'd like "Ordered List with Descriptions" to produce the same output as "Fake Ordered List with Descriptions"

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand: are you saying that the Org mode buffer would look like the "Ordered List with Descriptions" and that when you export to LaTeX, the output would appear like the "Fake Ordered List with Descriptions"? Or are you saying something else?

Comment: Just a small nit: what u call fake ordered list with description I'd  call ordered list with fake description.

Comment: How to get it I don't know but pls try inserting in "1." etc a [zero width space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (C-x 8 RET)  between the number eg 1 and the "." (don't have my m/c handy just now to try... Sorry)

Comment: @Rusi Fair enough.

Comment: @NickD Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: @Rusi not sure I understand how a zero width space is going to help in this case.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Did a ZWSP work? If y I'll elaborate. If no what's the point ? (It works here)

Comment: For that matter it works here without also! (org version 9.3.8)

Comment: Just to be clear "works" means "- 1. header :: body" works.  ie put the hyphen before the number. Then you don't need to boldify the header